# Undo “Remember my decision” in Eclipse for QuickDiff

Tags: eclipse

When choosing "Show annotation" in Eclipse I was asked if I want to use the QuickDiff feature and I said "no". Moreover, I checked "Remember my decision", and now I profoundly regret it. Now Eclipse goes to the "SVN Repository Exploring" perspective, instead of staying in the Java perspective and just show me the changes in the left vertical bar (the one with the line numbers).

Does anybody know how to re-enable QuickDiff? I went to the QuickDiff preferences page and tried to do it, but in vain.

I have an Eclipse EE Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, a colleague helped me to find the right option. See the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you type "diff" into the filter box of the **Preferences** dialog, you'll find it. In this case you also want to change the reference source to whatever version control system you are using.

[image: Preferences dialog]

Comment: It's not working. I had already tried changing the QuickDiff options before posting here.

Comment: Including the reference source?

Comment: Yes... What happens is that Eclipse goes to the "SVN Repository Exploring" perspective, and I want it to stay on my Java perspective and just show me the changes in the left vertical bar (the one with the line numbers).